# Convert date string without timezone to specific timezone moment object

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

In my application backend is applying user timezone and sending formatted date to UI. But when I am converting that string to date object. It is converting to user's system timezone. How can I change date string to specific timezone moment object not to user system timezone.

I am using moment-timezone library.

For ex. 07/26/2022 07:01:14 AM is already in GMT-5 but when I am converting this to moment object using `moment(new Date(dateString))`It is converting it to user system timezones.

How can I convert it to user defined timezone which is GMT-5

Comment: `is already in GMT-5` ... no it isn't - there is absolutely **nothing** about that string that specifies a timezone - `"2022-07-26T07:01:14-05:00"` would be what you expect

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant backend api is already doing timezone conversion and sending that to UI.

Comment: still ... nothing in that string conveys a timezone

Comment: Yes you are right there, but converting it to new Date(dateString) changing time to user's local timezone which I don't want.

Comment: if you read the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) you'll see that you can pass a "timezone" to `moment.tz` ... e.g. `moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");` - I've also added an answer that does not rely on the unmaintained moment libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just whipped this up - not using momentjs, because it's no longer maintained

```js
const input = "07/26/2022 07:01:14 AM"
const date= new Date(input);
//                                                             VVVVVV timezone fix
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset() + 5 * 60);
// date is now "07/26/2022 07:01:14 AM GMT-5"

// the following is just to show it's right
const verifyDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, {
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'full',
  timeZone: 'America/Bogota' // just picking a GMT-5 zone at random
}).format(date);

console.log(verifyDate)
// at this point
```